# Chow's lemma for non reduced schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Recall Chow's lemma:

> **Chow's Lemma**: If $X$ is a scheme that is proper over a noetherian base $S$ then
>   there exists a projective $S$-scheme $X'$ and a surjective
>   $S$-morphism $f : X'\to X$ that induces an isomorphism $f^{{-1}}(U)
>  \simeq U$ for some dense open $ U\subset X$.

I just looked at the [proof on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow%27s_lemma) (which presumably the one from EGA II) and found a slightly bothering detail. It starts by reducing to the irreducible case with the following argument:

> **Argument:** *Let $U_i \subset X_i$ be the open dense subsets in each irreducible component which satisfy the lemma. Then $U := \coprod_i (U_i -\bigcup_{j \ne i} X_j)$ is open dense in $X$ and satisfies the lemma.*

If we interpret **dense** as **dense in the zariski topology** then everything works fine throughout. But if we want it to mean **scheme theoretically dense** there's a problem with the argument as their might be an embedded point in $U_i \cap X_j$ (consider two lines intersecting at a double point).

Is there a way to "fix" the argument so that Chow's lemma will be true for **dense = scheme theoretically dense**?

If not is there a simple example of a non-reduced scheme for which this "strong" Chow's lemma fails?

Comment: This is far over my head, but have you considered posting this in Math Overflow as well?

Comment: Just a remark: the Stacks Project claims that you can say scheme-theoretically dense; see [Tag 0201](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0201).

Comment: Actually, the proof of Chow's Lemma in [Tag 0200](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0200) right before the one I linked to earlier says that $U$ can be turned into something that is scheme-theoretically dense.

Comment: Dear @TakumiMurayama, I don't see it. As I understood these two Sacks project tags, for sake of the proof, we may assume that $U$ is scheme-theoretically dense in $X$ by changing $X$ (not $U$!) and the remark (tag 0201) is about replacing $X'$ by something in which $f^{-1}U$ is scheme-theoretically dense, but that doesn't seem to help either. To use the Stacks project proof, we have to find a covering by affine opens, each of which is scheme-theoretically dense. But from that point, everything should go through without changes.

Comment: Dear @Ben I think you're right; I wasn't reading carefully enough. My apologies to both you and Saal Hardali!

Comment: No worries, I think it's a good Idea to consider the Stacks project proof and see if we can generalise it. It inspired the following idea for a possible counter-example, but I can't carry out the details right now, so I'm not sure if it works. Take a non-projective variety with a finite set of closed points which don't lie in a common affine open subset; (somehow) make these points embedded. Then there is no affine schematically dense open.

Comment: @Ben I think the following works for what you said: use ([Schröer's modification](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s000130050470) of) Kleiman's example, which is Hironaka's example of a proper non-projective variety with nilpotents added to two points lying in the two rational curves such that $A + B \equiv 0$. The two embedded points can't lie in the same affine open, by a theorem of Grothendieck cited in the Schröer's paper.

Comment: Dear Saal Hardali, I hate to tell you this, but unions of affines are not necessarily affine, see $\mathbb{P}^1$. More importantly, I'm not sure I completely understand your construction (do you mean *union* instead of *intersection*?), but I was expecting something along these lines to work. I'm glad you brought up an explicit example, @TakumiMurayama; I was sure such a thing exists since any normal, integral, proper, but non-projective surface has such a collection of points. ...

Comment: ... Showing that such a thing now gives a counter-example to Chow's lemma should go along these lines: If $U\subset X$ open and if $f\colon X'\to X$ is an isomorphism above $U$ with $X'$ projective, then $f^{-1}U = U$ is quasi-projective. Hence, any finite set of points on $U$ has an affine open neighbourhood. In particular, there is an open affine $V\subset U$ containing all associated points; but then $V$ is scheme-theoretically dense also in $X$.

Comment: @Ben Sorry I was confused earlier, said some horribly wrong stuff. I should go through your example more carefuly but I'd like to ask anyway: Are you completely convinced that Chow's lemma falis for non-reduced schemes?

Comment: I thought it should be true, but now I do think that there are counter-examples. I mean, all we need is a proper scheme without a quasi-projective, scheme-theoretically sense open. Now, if I recall correctly, every quasi-projective scheme has the property that any finite collection of points is contained in an affine open; in particular, every quasi-projective scheme should have a scheme-theoretically dense affine open...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is time to carefully put together what was said in the comments and to fill in the gaps. We will show that the 'strong' version of Chow's Lemma does not hold. More precisely: there exists $X$ such that any morphism $f\colon X'\to X$ from a projective scheme $X'$ fails to be an isomorphism over a scheme-theoretically dense open of $X$, even for proper irreducible (non-reduced, of course) schemes over an algebraically closed field. Of course, there will still be a Zariski-dense open. The good news is, inspection of the Stacks Project's proof ([tag 0200](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0200)) shows that the strong version holds as soon as $X$ has enough scheme-theoretically dense affine opens to constitute an open cover.

We work over some algebraically closed field $k$.

**Observation:** To get a counter-example, it suffices to construct a proper $k$-scheme which does not admit an affine scheme-theoretically dense open.

In fact, if a proper $k$-scheme $X$ satisfies the strong lemma of Chow, i.e., if there exists a morphism $f\colon X'\to X$ where $X'$ is projective and which is an isomorphism over a scheme-theoretically dense open $U\subset X$, then $U\cong f^{-1}U\subset X'$ is quasi-projective and contains all the associated points of $X$.
By [Stacks' tag 01ZY](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ZY), the finite subset $\mathrm{Ass}(X) =: T\subset U$ is contained in an affine open $V\subset U$; any such $V$ is then a scheme-theoretically dense affine open in $X$.

**The strategy** is to start with a proper variety $X$ which contains a finite subset $T\subset X$ of points which is not contained in any affine open and then pass to another proper scheme $Y$ where the points of $T$ are thickened to become associated points.

Let me now explain one way to accomplish the thickening. (You can jump to the lemma below if you don't care how it's done.) The approach indicated in the comments also seems to work, after appropriate modifications.
Assume that $X$ is a locally noetherian scheme and let $T\subset X$ be a closed sub-scheme with ideal sheaf $\mathscr{I}\subset \mathcal{O}_X$.
Consider the sub-scheme $Y\subset \mathbb{A}^1_{X} = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_X[t])$ defined by the ideal $\mathscr{J} := t^2+t\mathscr{I}$ with its natural morphism $\varphi\colon Y = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_X[t]/\mathscr{J})\to X$. (I hope everyone can deal with this abuse of notation?) The projection $\mathcal{O}_X[t]\to \mathcal{O}_X$ onto degree zero descends to $\mathcal{O}_Y$ and this gives rise to a section $\iota\colon X\to Y$ of $\varphi\colon Y\to X$; thus, $X$ is in a natural way a sub-scheme of $Y$ and it is easy to see that if $X$ is reduced, this gives rise to a canonical isomorphism $X\cong Y_{red.}\subset Y$. More importantly, in any case, it shows that $\mathcal{O}_Y = \mathcal{O}_X\oplus t\mathcal{O}_X$ and $t\mathcal{O}_Y = t\mathcal{O}_X$.
In particular, $$\mathrm{ann}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(t) = \mathscr{I}+t\mathcal{O}_Y = \mathscr{I}+t\mathcal{O}_X$$ and, therefore, if $\eta\in X$ is the generic point of an irreducible component of $T$, so that $\mathscr{I}_\eta\supset\mathfrak{m}_{X,\eta}^n$ for some $n$, then $\mathrm{ann}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(t)_\eta = \mathscr{I}_\eta+t\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}\supset \mathfrak{m}_{X,\eta}^n+t\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}\supset \mathfrak{m}_{Y,\eta}^n$. Thus, $\mathfrak{m}_{Y,\eta}$ is an associated prime of $\mathcal{O}_{Y,\eta}$.
This shows:

**Lemma** — Let $X$ be a locally noetherian scheme and $T\subset X$ a closed sub-scheme. Then there exists a bijective closed immersion $\iota\colon X\to Y$ which is an isomorphism outside $T$, and which maps the generic points of $T$ to associated points of $Y$. Furthermore, $\iota$ has a retraction $Y\to X$ which is a finite morphism.

Finally, let $X$ be a proper, integral $k$-variety with a finite set of closed points $T\subset X$ which is not contained in an affine open of $X$. For example, we can take $X$ to be any non-projective, proper, normal, integral surface and $T$ the set of non-factorial points (cf. Kleiman, Toward a numerical criterion of ampleness, IV Cor. 4). Alternatively, as Takumi Murayama has pointed out in the comments, we could take Hironaka's non-projective three-fold and two points, one on each of the two curves involved in the construction except the intersection points.

Let $Y\supset X$ be the thickening of $T$ as described in the lemma. By finiteness of the morphism $Y\to X$, $Y$ is proper too.
Then $Y$ admits no scheme-theoretically dense affine open since $\iota\colon X\to Y$ is affine and so any such would give rise to an affine open in $X$ containing all of $T$.
By the above observation, this is all we need to get a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up! One slight correction about the Hironaka example. Let $A$ and $B$ be the two rational curves in Hironaka's threefold $X$ such that $A + B \equiv 0$. Then, the points you introduce infinitesimals at should be $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

Comment: Thank you, @TakumiMurayama — I just corrected it.

Comment: @Ben Thanks! I only skimmed so far though. It'll take me a few days to really go through all this.

Comment: If something's unclear let me know.